# How to change master page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, custom-masterpage, feature-receiver

I would like to change master page, how would I do that in SharePoint 2013

Also, I want to do same using programming in a feature receiver.

Comment: Please add more details! What do you mean with change master page? do you mean to change the design of master page or switch between master pages , also check how to switch masterpage in SP 2013 http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/07/21/sharepoint-2013-how-to-change-the-master-page-of-your-sharepoint-site/

Comment: I got the answers. I want to switch from default to custom.

Comment: Why negative vote?

Comment: Hi @Rinku your question has been flagged from the community members as low quality so it's downvoted, Please edit your question and add some details to help future visitors to understand your question Thanks!

Comment: @M.Qassas i will take care about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in a full trust farm solution then you can programmatically apply master page.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    try
    {
        using (SPWeb currentWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
        {
            using (SPSite currentSite = currentWeb.Site)
            {
                string masterPageUrl = string.Format("{0}/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomTeamSite.master", currentSite.ServerRelativeUrl).Replace("//", "/");
                currentWeb.CustomMasterUrl = masterPageUrl;
                currentWeb.MasterUrl = masterPageUrl;
                currentWeb.Update();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errorMessage = string.Format("An exception occured while trying to activate the feature. Message: '{0}'.", ex.Message);
        throw new SPException(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

on deactivation of feature

```
public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    try
    {
        using (SPWeb currentWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
        {
            using (SPSite currentSite = currentWeb.Site)
            {
                string masterPageUrl = string.Format("{0}/_catalogs/masterpage/default.master", currentSite.ServerRelativeUrl).Replace("//", "/");
                currentWeb.CustomMasterUrl = masterPageUrl;
                currentWeb.MasterUrl = masterPageUrl;
                currentWeb.Update();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string errorMessage = string.Format("An exception occured while trying to deactivate the feature. Message: '{0}'.", ex.Message);
        throw new SPException(errorMessage);
    }
}
```